# Write data to with userID and read data with userID

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to write data to firebase with a userID, because later I only want to retrieve the data the user saved. The first problem is when I read data to firebase only the values change, but I want that the values append to firebase with the userID.

I only want to retrieve the data with the UserId of the current user, but when I load it I get all informations from all users.

1. I already tried to change the childadded or valuetype.
2. I already tried to set after the first child "SavedWoman" an other child with the current userID but it don't work.

   ```
   let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
   let SavedProduct : [String: Any] = ["ImageURL": FImage1[picturenumber], "Price" : Price[picturenumber]]
   Database.database().reference().child("SavedWoman").child(userID!).setValue(SavedProduct)
   ```

   I also tried:

   ```
   refData = Database.database().reference().child("SavedWoman") /*here I already tried to set the userID */


   refData.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapchot) in
       if snapchot.childrenCount>0  {

           for data in snapchot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot] {

               let DataObject = data.value as? [String: AnyObject]
               let ImageObject = DataObject?["ImageURL"]
               let PriceObject = DataObject?["Price"]

              let data1 = DataModel(ImageURL: ImageObject as! String?, Price: PriceObject as! String?)

               self.DataList.append(data1)

           }

           self.tableView.reloadData()

       }
   })
   ```

Comment: Your current code in the second snippet will read all data under `SavedWoman`. Please replace the `/*here I already tried to set the userID */` with the code that you actually used to do that.

Comment: I had do this, but it does not work!

Comment: It's unclear what the actual issue is. Is the data being stored in Firebase correctly? You can check it by using your firebase console on the website to take a look. If it is, the second piece of code in the question reads all the child nodes of Saved Woman,  as Frank mentioned. What is the expected behavior? Can you clarify what the actual issue is?